# Error al crear una nueva pagina en asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Muy buenas estoy desarrollando una pagina web pero tengo un problema ahora al crear una nueva pagina al querer abrirla en mi pagina web me salta este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

@David Acabo de revisar y si los nombres están correctos pero revise y al compilar tengo este error no se si tenga algo que ver [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aqui esta mi estructura [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo primero de todo revisa que el nombre de tu paginas y tu codeBehind se llamen de la misma forma.
Es posible que al generar los archivos en la primera línea de tu código se estén referenciando mal.
Si es posible envía una imagen de tu explorador de proyectos para ver la estructura.
Entiendo que el proyecto como tal te compila y funciona, solo te da el error al cargar desde tu frontend esta página.
Otro posible error es que tengas alguna carpeta creada y no se esté referenciando correctamente. Saludos.

Comment: Buenas este error es extraño y no lo conozco aunque he encontrado esto que quizá te pueda ayudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511822/msbuild-wont-compile-my-solution-it-fails-with-critical-and-ridiculous-errors Que la versión del compilador esté correcta respecto al lenguaje de construcción del framework. Por otra parte la estructura parece correcta sin subFolders, revisa que en la primera línea del archivo KPIGrafico.aspx y KPIGrafico.aspx.cs (CodeBehind) estén bien referenciadas ya que puede vernir por ahí el problema. Saludos.

Comment: cuantos proyectos tienes en la solucion? porque este que causa problemas es un CRM.Web.Tests, o sea no es un proyecto web donde estan los aspx, es un proyecto de Test. Es correcto que este ese proyecto?